# How do I deny a particular user from getting root ( through su ) in a terminal by changing the /etc/pam.d/su ? Pam based controlling is required

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, pam, pam-environment

There are two users in ubuntu (let's call them `user1` and `user2`). Currently, `user1`  can get access root access using the below commands:

```
user1@sai:~$ su
Password: 
root@sai:/home/user1#
```

However, I want to deny `user1` from getting root access, and instead allow `user2` to get root access through `sudo` when desired by modifying the Pam configuration file in `/etc/pam.d/su` file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is what `/etc/sudoers` does with the help of some groups.

By default, if a user is a member of group `admin` or group `sudo`, they'll have the ability to run commands as the root user. So, we can just remove the user from these two groups:

```
sudo gpasswd -d sudo user1
sudo gpasswd -d admin user1
```

Note that this will *not* take effect immediately. `user1` must log out and back in for this change to take effect.

To give `user2` access to root, you may add them to either of these groups. Personally, I prefer to add them to the `sudo` group, like so:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo user2
```

Again, `user2` needs to log out and back in for these settings to take effect.

---

Note, though, that it may be possible for `user1` to have a record in the `/etc/sudoers` file, in which case you need to delete that record.

When editing `/etc/sudoers`, ***never*** edit it by hand! Instead, use the `visudo` command, which will validate that you're not going to accidentally break your config irreversibly. Execute this with the `sudo visudo` command.

Comment: how to do the same thing for `su` ? Same procedure or different ?

Comment: `su` is a different beast entirely. Instead of using current user permissions, `su` uses the target user. Any user can theoretically run `su`, but only users that know `root`'s (or whoever the target user is in the case of `su <user>`) password will be able to use it to escalate.